# Realtek HD Audio Driver failed to build

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, 15.04, realtek

I have Ubuntu 15.04 x64 running on a Gigabyte GA-Z87X-UD4H with Realtek ALC898. The audio works mostly out of the box and the device is detected as my card1 (card0 is IntelHDA). The problem I'm having is with the front panel.

Firstly, front panel detection does not work at all. Second of all, when I manually select the headphones plugged in the front panel, I get sound from my speakers as well.

So I decided to install the latest alsa drivers from Ubuntu's official page [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages). But as you can see, they don't have a version pre-built.

Thus, I decided to build Realtek drivers from source, but I get an error when compiling - [ERROR LOG](http://pastebin.com/a3Esi6Lu).

I am hoping someone can help me diagnose the compilation error, so I can try and install the driver. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "Realtek" drivers? Something downloaded from the Realteak website, or drivers from Ubuntu for your sound chip?

Comment: Realtek drivers are the Linux drivers provided from Realtek for my chip. They are open source and you can build them on Ubuntu. The problem is the build fails and the simple fixes I tried had no effect - build errors every time. It seems however Canonical are also struggling to build these drivers for Ubuntu and no fix is in sight.

Comment: The problem is that your build system is using `-Werror`, but the Realtek package does not expect that. Apparently, the Realtek package is outdated. Please note that Realtek also puts their changes into the kernel drivers; if an update to the newest kernel does not help, the Rt-Linux-HDaudio package is unlikely to help either.

Comment: thanks @CL. but unfortunately, Ubuntu is not on the latest kernel. How do I compile without -Werror or use a different env? I just want to be able to compile it properly (as instructions are scarce) and test if it fixes my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with this for a while. I have, however, found a solution today for getting the output to not come in through the mic.

It turns out that the mic is set to stereo, and I am guessing my port is mono. Or it's the other way around. Either way, this was the fix for me:

1. Run PulseAudio Volume Control (or pavucontrol from the ALT+F2 menu)
2. Under "Input Devices" find your mic (Mine was "Front Microphone")
3. Deselect the "Lock Channels Together" button (looks like a lock)
4. Move the left channel to "Silent".

   Note: It may be a different channel for you. You may want to also try turning on some music or something to test which channel is the mic and which is the audio
5. Test!

I hope this helps!